# Ordered linked list gives null pointer when trying to insert largest value

Tags: java

```
 public void insert(int data)
        {
            Node newNode = new Node(data);
            Node current = head;
            Node prev = null;

            if(head == null)
            {
                head = newNode;
            }
            else
            {   
                while(data > current.data && current != null)
                {
                    prev = current;
                    current = current.next;
                }

                if(prev == null)
                {
                    newNode.next = current;
                    head = newNode;
                }
                else
                {
                    prev.next = newNode;
                    newNode.next = current;
                }
            }
```

This is an insert method for an ordered link list, smallest integer going to the head. Everything goes fine with this method until I try to insert a larger value than the value that I first added. when I try to add a new larger value it gives a null pointer exception, and this is the only time it give it.  I feel as though my logic is fine when I checked it, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `"I feel as though my logic is fine when I checked it, anyone have any ideas?"` -- stating the obvious, you know that your logic is not fine (else you wouldn't be having this problem). If this were my code and problem, I'd use my IDE's debugger and run the code through the debugger, inspecting fields, finding the error and then solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the order of conditions inside

```
while(data > current.data && current != null)
```

So it should be

```
while(current != null && data > current.data)
```

That's because Java `&&` operator starts with checking from the left, so no matter if `current` is null or not it will try to call `data` on this